# Is it possible to aggregate with multiple conditions on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a pricing collection and i want to query the biggest price change over time depending on the seller and i have not clue how to accomplish this in a single query.

The collection includes

```
_id
partNumber
seller
price
createdAt
```

Every day for each product about 30 prices should get inserted, but in a real world that is not 100%...

so i was thinking about this.

1. get the first price where date <= (currentDate - compare range days) for partNumber and seller
2. get the newest price for partNumber and seller
3. diff the prices
4. sort by diff

Is that possible with mongodb aggregate or something else?

Comment: can you please add sample collection data and response you want acc to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume we have 2 sellers A and B. We have taken a set of data as below (assuming part Number are same or you can change it as well):

```
/* 1 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb442"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "B",
    "price" : 15,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-11T16:13:31.451+05:30")
},

/* 2 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb441"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "A",
    "price" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-11T16:13:31.451+05:30")
},

/* 3 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb440"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "B",
    "price" : 10,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-10T16:13:31.451+05:30")
},

/* 4 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb43f"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "A",
    "price" : 10,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-10T16:13:31.451+05:30")
},

/* 5 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb43e"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "B",
    "price" : 7,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T16:13:31.451+05:30")
},

/* 6 createdAt:18/10/2019, 16:48:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da99f8bd4ce6a7d8bebb43d"),
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "seller" : "A",
    "price" : 5,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T16:13:31.451+05:30")
}
```

Our Query will be as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { seller: "$seller", partNumber: "$partNumber" },
            lastSalesPrice: { $last: "$price" },
            firstSalesPrice: { $first: "$price" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            seller: "$_id.seller",
            partNumber: "$_id.partNumber",
            lastSalesPrice: "$lastSalesPrice",
            firstSalesPrice: "$firstSalesPrice",
            diff: { $subtract: ["$lastSalesPrice", "$firstSalesPrice" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "diff": -1 }
    }
])
```

Result of above query will be as follow:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "seller" : "B",
        "partNumber" : 1
    },
    "seller" : "B",
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "lastSalesPrice" : 15,
    "firstSalesPrice" : 7,
    "diff" : 8
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "seller" : "A",
        "partNumber" : 1
    },
    "seller" : "A",
    "partNumber" : 1,
    "lastSalesPrice" : 1,
    "firstSalesPrice" : 5,
    "diff" : -4
}
```

Comment: this looks great, but there is one question left.
what happens if Seller B has no entry for 2019-10-09 to tell the query then use the next older one.

Comment: In that case, it will automatically pick the first sale price from the date 2019-10-10. I tried at my end and it is working, you can also try at your end.

Comment: it is true, but i need to limit the data to (now - 30 days) for example and then in this case there is no older entry.

Comment: at this point a thought about performance. Not to add more  to the pipeline as really needed. I made sure that for every day the record exists and then your solution works perfect. Thank you very much!